# How to #include and exclude specific script from the current running script by hotkeys?

Tags: autohotkey

- I have 2 AHK scripts,  the 1st one is named (HotstringsEnglish.ah) and it  contains some Hotstrings for English.
- The 2nd (HotStringsFrench.ahk), it contains some Hotstrings for French.

I want when I click ^e, the (HotstringsEnglish.ahk) to be included in the current running script,
But when clicking ^f, I want the (HotStringsFrench.ahk) to be included in the current running script and exclude the 1st one (HotstringsEnglish.ahk) from the current running script.

I've tried this but did't work :

```
#If WinActive("Browse ahk_exe anki.exe")
^e::#include HotStringsEnglish.ahk
^f::#include HotStringsFrench.ahk
#If
```

- The problem is when clicking ^e, the (HotstringsEnglish.ahk) included succsesfuly in the current running script and it stills included, But when clicking ^f the (HotStringsFrench.ahk) doesn't include.
- This is an alternative solution to the problem that I posted here:https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=123108

Any help to do so please!

Comment: Can we have a, for example, pastebin link to the script? The hotstrings themselves do not have to be included.

Comment: is there are reason why you must store the hotstrings in 2 different files? Wouldn't creating one big file with both languages be much easier?

Comment: `#If WinActive("Browse ahk_exe anki.exe")` Is a bit weird. The command should be followed by the WinTitle which would be something like `User 1 - Anki` please read https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_IfWinActive.htm

Comment: I hope you see the related topic mentioned in the question to know better What I'm looking for.I want to do that when I'm in the Anki browse ("Browse ahk_exe anki.exe")

Comment: You seem to have combined multiple problems into one question (if I understand you correctly)

Comment: If you are in the Anki Browser the title will just be `Browse (x of y cards selected)` so AHK won't be able to detect which deck you currently have selected (even if you use that Add-on for Anki). This is not fixable unless you write your own plugin for Anki

Comment: If you type Ctrl-e then it will include the HotStringsEnglish forever until the end of time. They do not get "unincluded". You should probably not be using #include in this way.

Comment: Can you show us a bit of HotstringsEnglish.ahk (e.g. the first 3 lines)?

Comment: I've got a solution that does exactly what I want. I hope you see it here (https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/17whrix/how_to_include_and_exclude_specific_script_from/). Is there any way to reduce the code by create a function or anything that manipulates all those variables?
Because in the case I have many decks for different objects and hotsrings for each object, the script will be too long.

Answer (score 1):

#Include is a directive. Directives cannot be executed conditionally or per hotkey or per command. The only solution is to use another included script that you can change the content this way:

```
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstrings_Lang.ahk

#IfWinActive Browse ahk_exe anki.exe

^e::
FileAppend,
(
#Include HotStringsEnglish.ahk
), %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstrings_Lang_tmp.ahk
Sleep, 300
FileMove, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstrings_Lang_tmp.ahk, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstrings_Lang.ahk, 1 ; overwrite
Sleep, 300 
Reload
return

^f::
FileAppend,
(
#Include HotStringsFrench.ahk
), %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstrings_Lang_tmp.ahk
Sleep, 300
FileMove, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstrings_Lang_tmp.ahk, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstrings_Lang.ahk, 1 ; overwrite
Sleep, 300 
Reload
return

#IfWinActive
```

Note that you have to create the script `Hotstrings_Lang.ahk` manually if it doesn't already exist.